# Euclidean geometry book for math contests

Tags: geometry, contest-math, book-recommendation

I'm a last year high school student, I'm looking for a "short" (by short I mean, not over 250 pages) Euclidean geometry book that covers topics linked to euclidean geometry of math contests, I have a decent knowledge in the topic thus I'm looking for a book to tackle a bit more advanced stuff. By searching a bit on the internet I found this one book: "[Geometry revisited by Coxeter & Greitzer](http://www.aproged.pt/biblioteca/geometryrevisited_coxetergreitzer.pdf)", I've read through the content and it seemed what I was looking for, is the book good for my purpose? any better suggestion?

Comment: See [my FAQ](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/about.html#books) for a few suggestions (Honsberger is a fun read, Altshiller-Court is comprehensive and systematic, Johnson is somewhat obsolete but has some gems), but keep in mind that several new books have come out since 2006 (in particular, Hadamard's Planimetry in English with 2-3 companion volumes containing problems and solutions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great book is

Evan Chen, *[Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883858398)*

While something a bit more elementary, but containing some hard problems is

Louridas & Rassias, *[Problem-Solving and Selected Topics in Euclidean Geometry](http://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Problem-Solving%20and%20Selected%20Topics%20in%20Euclidean%20Geometry%20In%20the%20Spirit%20of%20the%20Mathematical%20Olympiads%20-%20Louridas,%20Rassias%20(2013).pdf)*

A great Dover edition with famous problems and less famous is

Aref & Wernick, *[Problems and Solutions in Euclidean Geometry](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Problems-Solutions-Euclidean-Geometry-Mathematics/dp/0486477207/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1546626116&sr=8-12&keywords=euclidean%20dover)*

Comment: while EGMO is a fantastic book, it's slightly over OP's request of 250 pages. I still think it's worth a read though

Answer (score 3):

There are two following very good books:

1. A.V.Akopyan. Geometry in pictures.

2.V.V.Prasolov. Problems in Plane Geometry.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the book myself, but a former participant in the International Mathematical Olympiads that I am acquainted with suggested *Plane Euclidean Geometry: Theory and Problems*, by A. D. Gardiner and C. J. Bradley, a suggestion which is also given [here](http://people.bath.ac.uk/masgcs/geo.pdf).